# Finding the magnitude of the sum of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I know that the sum of the square of the elements in the vector u has to equal to 25 and for v it has equal 9. We also know the dot product of the two vectors is -1. Where do I go on from besides guessing and checking the elements?

Answer (score 3):

$$||u+v||^2 = ||u||^2+2u\cdot v +||v||^2.$$

Comment: Where for each $u \in \mathbb{R}^n, \ ||u|| = u \cdot u$.